# Как написать функцию для селектора jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#hitsale button, #photogalery button").click(function() {

})
```

Надо чтобы по клику на выделенные кнопки открывалось всплывающее окно (`#callOrderModal`)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style>
  .popap {
    position: absolute;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    display:block;
  }

  .hide {
    display:none;
  }
</style>

<div id="callOrderModal" class="hide">
  Popap
</div>

<div id="hitsale"> Кнопка</div>

 <script>
$('#hitsale').click(function() {
  $('#callOrderModal').removeClass('hide');
  $('#callOrderModal').addClass('popap');
});
</script>
```